# How do you save an open document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, save

I have the following code:

```
        private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application XcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();


            XcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                XcelApp.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                try // catches null cells and ignores
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j += 2)
                    {
                        XcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

                    }
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException);
                }
            }
             XcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
             XcelApp.Visible = true;
            string pathway = @"C:\Temp\" + txtComputer.Text + "." + lblVersion.Text + "." + lblProduct.Text + ".csv";
            
            XcelApp.GetSaveAsFilename(pathway, "CSV (Comma Delimited) (*.csv), *.csv",2, DialogResult.OK);

        }
    }
```

This outputs a datagridview to an excel spreadsheet, opens it and then opens the save file dialogue box to save the document as CSV.
I have several issues:

1. If I click save, it seems to ignore the save completely and no document is saved.
2. Ideally I'd like this to autosave, I'm not too bothered about it opening at all.
3. Excel.Application doesn't give a Save() or a SaveAs() method to do any of the above so I assume I am using the incorrect reference. What would I use so I can save this doc automatically?

Thanks

Comment: it's the workbook Object that has the SaveAs /Save methods, so: you should have gotten a reference to the Workbook object when creating it with the Add() method. Then you use that reference: wb.SaveAs(....). Look this up in the Excel VBA docs and then transfer to C# for easier understanding

Comment: Thanks @MacroMarc. I had been playing about with workbook and was getting errors. However following your confirmation, I have posted the code I got working below.

Comment: You should also be accessing the `Workbook.Cells` etc, not the `Application`, as that is only what is in focus. E.g. you can do this whole thing with the workbook hidden like that

Comment: Well done, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application XcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = XcelApp.Workbooks.Add();

            for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                XcelApp.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                try // catches null cells and ignores
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j += 2)
                    {
                        XcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

                    }
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException);
                }
            }

            string pathway = @"C:\Temp\" + txtComputer.Text + "." + lblVersion.Text + "." + lblProduct.Text + ".csv";
            excelWorkBook.SaveAs(pathway, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV); 
            XcelApp.Workbooks.Close();

        }
    }
```